# Syntax Error with mysql in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse

I don' t understand why eclipse tell me this error for this query:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from '"+ value3+ "' where Name='" + value1 + "' and Password='"+ value2 + "'");
```

error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''f' where Name='f' and Password='f'' at line 1
```

Comment: 1. Use backticks to escape table and column names. 2. Use prepared statements instead of patching thinks together.

Comment: be careful though. concatenating sql statements like that can lead to SQL injection vulnerarbilities. have a look at prepared statements.

Comment: why suffer using above statement try using PreparedStatement lot more easier to understand and better way of coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Try this.

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from `" + value3 + "` where Name='" +
               value1 + "' and Password='"+ value2 + "'");
```

See here:
[MySQL Identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

The identifier quote character is the backtick ("`") in MySQL.

2) Also, as you're not using PreparedStatement, if your Name or 
Password contains ' you will have issues. Your code is vulnerable 
to SQL injection.

See also:
[PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) 
[SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Some explanation, what you actually changed and why you did so, would be nice as well.

Comment: you are only the BEST, i' ve passed all the afternoon to get some solution!!! tnks you so much!!!

Comment: i dont understand when you talk about sql injection can you explain pretty well?

Comment: Well, you can Google it. Check this for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: it is a school project, i' m not worried about.

Comment: let me understand, if it is a school project it will have sql injection but if it is for your real job it would not have security flaws?, CiMat, always do the best when programming please. :)